# How to protect from water seeping into the home via gap in door

Tags: water, doors, door-frame, rain

When there's a rain and it smashes on the door then water slowly seeps into the flat because there's a gap between door and the door frame.

As of now I'm blocking the space with some cloth when I'm in home.

But if it rains when I'm not in the home then there's a water puddle in the living room.

I want to try a solution which will work out in long term.

I could attach a rain deflector like below but it will ruin all the designer wood curving work that's done on the door and frame.

[image]

I'm looking for a solution which is not an eyesore as well.

Comment: Maybe add a roof over the door?   A pic of the entire front will be helpful.

Comment: Is there not a sweep on the bottom of the door? If not, remove the door and staple a sweep on.

Comment: There are many types of door weather stripping that are made to keep weather out(rain, heat ,and cold) that are made to seal gaps.  Unless you live in the one place that has perfect weather, then sealing gaps should number one job.

Comment: @RMDman - It has a concrete roof but during the rain and when the wind is blowing bit heavily then this problem happens

Comment: @crip659 - I'd like to just keep the rain out but how to seal the gap of a moving door elegantly

Comment: @matt. - I checked out many sweeps but it's not looking good on my door , any good looking sweep ?

Comment: There are many different types of weather stripping for door bottoms that are made for moving doors.

Comment: @CuriousMan You should be able to find a sweep that matches the thickness of your door and staples on the bottom, doesn't wrap around the edges of the door. I see them all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for a kerfed style door sweep or a simple glue/staple on sweep like this ([Amazon item](https://%20https://a.co/d/0bZvQHr))

[image: door sweep]

A kerfed style requires a cut in the bottom of the door and can snap in/out.